# Passing data from a View to another view inside a tabcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am having issues passing data from a View to another view that has a relationship with a Tab Controller. I got it to work from one view to another view...

if I set the segue from the mainView directly to the secondView, it works! however if i set the segue to go to the tab bar controller (which will call the secondView), it does`t...

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender(id)sender {
 secondView *secView = [segue destinationViewController]
 secView.ext = @".com";
}
```

If I had to guess I would say that destinationViewController is the problem.. as the destination view controller is the tab bar controller and not the secondView

Comment: It'd be easier to understand your questions if you'd 1) follow the usual Objective-C naming convention and name your classes starting with a capital letter, and 2) give your classes names that aren't misleading. `secondView` looks to an experienced Obj-C programmer like a variable that points to an instance of `UIView`, not a class derived from `UIViewController`. `SecondViewController` would be much better name than `secondView`. In return, you'll be more likely to get better answers in greater quantity.

Comment: passing data can happen via _delegates_, _notification_ or even using the common _model_, which one of these have you intended to use?

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you wrote, and look at your code -- you've essentially answered your own question. You've connected the segue to something other than an instance of `secondView`. Then, you get the segue's `destinationViewController` (which you know is a tab controller) and treat it as though it were a `secondView`.

You don't say how it fails, but I wouldn't be surprised if you get an error to the effect that UITabBarController doesn't have a `-setExt:` method.

Comment: I can`t get it to work tho... I was essential asking for some help on how to solve it.. if i link the segue directly to the secondView, the tab controller won`t load!

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things:

1. Create a Tab Bar Controller class, add a property inside it, assign it a value in `prepareForSegue`, then use `[self.tabBarController]` in `secondView.m` to access it, or
2. Change your  `secondView *secView = [segue destinationViewController]` line to:

   ```
   secondView *secView =  [[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]
   ```